# Use awk and grep to string without echo and return value to variable

Tags: bash, awk

There is answer to how to use grep or awk without echo, but I want that return value to variable. Like below:

```
a="hello world"
value="$a" | grep "world" | awk '{print $NF}'
echo $value
```

But value is empty.
I don't want use echo to get value like below:

```
value=$(echo "$a" | grep "world" | awk '{print $NF}')
```

Can I get that first code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try to use following in case you don't want to use `echo`, I am using here string concept. Also you need NOT to use `grep` since `awk` itself could search the keywords in Input_file or variable's values.

```
a="hello world"
value=$(awk '/world/{print $NF}' <<<"$a")
echo "$value"
```

You could get more information from `man bash` about `Here Strings` as follows.

> Here Strings    A variant of here documents, the format is:
>
> ```
>       <<<word
> ```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP is saying OP doesn't want to have `Here Strings` concept too then may be following could help here.

```
a="hello world"
value=$(awk -v val="$a" 'BEGIN{num=split(val, array," ");print array[num]}')
echo "$value"
```

Comment: This is perfect answer to my question. Thank you.

Comment: @N00b, glad that it helped you. Give it sometime and try to select an answer out of all answers too to close the thread completely.

Comment: This is too late, but I forgot to mention that I don't want use subshell $(), can I do without it?

Comment: Yes, but this answers to my first question perfect so I have to accept that.

Comment: @N00b, please check my EDIT solution and let me know then?

Comment: Edited one is better in this case because I want to run my code faster and it is faster way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

When you are sure that `world`is part of the string, you can use

```
value=${a//* }
```

## or

```
value=${a##* }
```

(Not a solution using `awk` but added in view of OP's comment he "wants to run his code faster").

Comment: Thanks for this. This is the fastest way to this far. And my final goal is not use awk, grep, sed or anything that is slowing my code run down.

Comment: Can I somehow get last and second last words from string with that your solution?

Comment: No, that would be `awk`, `sed -r 's/.* (\w \w)$/\1/'` or `grep -Eo "[^ ]* [^ ]*$"`.